# Why ConfigureAwait(false) does not work while Task.Run() works?

Tags: c#, async-await, configureawait

I'm calling an `async` library method with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. But, I still end up with deadlock. (I'm using it in ASP.NET controller API)
But, if I use the same method wrapped into `Task.Run()` it works fine.

My understanding is, if the libraries method is not using `ConfigureAwait` internally then adding `ConfigureAwait` won't solve the problem as in the library call it will result in deadlock (we block on it by using `.Result`). But, if that's the case why does it work in `Task.Run()` as it will fail to continue in same context/thread.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) talks about it. Btw, I have read plenty of articles by Stephen Cleary. But, why Task.Run() works is a mystery.

Code snippet:

```
// This Create Method results in Deadlock
public async Task<string> Create(MyConfig config)
{
        Document doc = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, config).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return doc.Id;
}

// Uses Task.Run() which works properly, why??
public string Create(MyConfig config)
{
    Document doc = Task.Run(() => Client.CreateDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, config)).Result;
    return doc.Id;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateConfig(MyConfig config)
{
     string id = Create(config).Result;
     return Json(id);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first example, the implementation of `Client.CreateDocumentAsync` is deadlocking because it is trying to execute a continuation using the current `SynchronizationContext`.

When using `Task.Run`, the delegate will be invoked on a ThreadPool thread, this means there will be no current `SynchronizationContext` so all continuations will be resumed using a ThreadPool thread. This means it will not deadlock.

Out of interest, why is your `CreateConfig` method not async? Most recent versions of MVC and WebAPI support asynchronous methods, getting rid of the `.Result` would be the best solution.

Comment: Shouldn't use of ConfigureAwait(false) ensure continuation using ThreadPool? and yes, I have made CreateConfig method async. But, wanted to understand the concept better exactly on why Task.Run() doesn't create any problems.

Comment: @KrunalModi `ConfigureAwait(false)` only configures the continuations to use the threadpool, not the invocation of `Client.CreateDocumentAsync`

Comment: @KrunalModi there is no point using `ConfigureAwait` with an async call that internally has another async call that *is not* used with `ConfigureAwait`. `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used *almost* anywhere, and especially in libraries. Only the top level calls (those in the UI Synchronization Context) don't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` because the continuation should be executed in the UI Synchronization Context. For libraries that don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally, using `await Task.Run(()=> ...)` or `await Task.Run(()=> ...).ConfigureAwait(false)` is a good workaround.

Answer (score 16):

I believe Lukazoid is correct. To put it another way...

```
// This Create Method results in Deadlock
public async Task<string> Create(MyConfig config)
{
  Document doc = await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, config).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return doc.Id;
}
```

You can't just stick a `ConfigureAwait(false)` at one level and have it magically prevent deadlocks. `ConfigureAwait(false)` can only prevent deadlocks if it is used by every `await` in the transitive closure of that method and all methods it calls.

In other words, `ConfigureAwait(false)` needs to be used for every `await` in `Create` (which it is), and it also needs to be used for every `await` in `CreateDocumentAsync` (which we don't know), and it also needs to be used for every `await` in every method that `CreateDocumentAsync` calls, etc.

This is one reason why it is such a brittle "solution" to the deadlock problem.

Comment: Every async call should be adequately documented on that matter in order to take the right decision. Using `await [async call].ConfigureAwait(false)` or `await Task.Run(async ()=> await [async call]).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis: That would be great in theory, but in reality a missing `ConfigureAwait(false)` is usually a mistake. So the documentation would just be wrong.

Comment: can we say that "all the way configreawait(false)" like it is said "all the way await"?

Comment: @batmaci: Yes, in the sense that if you're going to use it, it's best to use it all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation: i also noticed that doing this will also result in a deadlock

```
private string Create(Task<Document> task)
{
    var doc = Task.Run(() => task).Result;
    return doc.Id;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateConfig(MyConfig config)
{
     var task = Client.CreateDocumentAsync(CollectionUri, config);
     var id = Create(task).Result;
     return Json(id);
}
```

So even running things on the thread pool may not be the ultimate solution. It seems an equally import factor to consider is what `SynchonizationContext` was in effect when the **async method's task** was created.